# ASP.NET Core execute javascript from controller

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, asp.net-core

I have a form that I would like to call a JavaScript function I have when I click on the button.

Very basic form:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="">
     <input asp-for="@search" autofocus />
     <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript function:

```
function getmap(location) {
        var completeaddress = location;
        mapcode.geocode({ 'address': completeaddress }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                diag.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var hint = new google.maps.Marker({
                    diag: diag,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    icon: {
                        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                        url: 'images/Markers/BasicMarker.png'
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Location Not Tracked. ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

My empty function in my controller:

```
public IActionResult Search()
{

    return View();
}
```

Basically I'd like to send the new location from the asp controller to the JavaScript and the map would be updated.

Comment: I think you're thinking about this a bit backwards. The javascript should likely call the ASP controller action to retrieve the desired value, then execute the function with the result.

Comment: Alright, I'm quite new to web actually. (I mean less than 2 days) I mainly work for desktop / cloud softwares. Could you enlighten me or give me a lead on how I should proceed ?